# Scaling Magento 2 on multiple containers in production with generated code

Tags: magento2.2.2, code-generation, docker, containers

I'm working on some auto-scaling Kubernetes infrastructure to run Magento 2, and I noticed that when I start new containers, I can't have the `generated/` directory automatically compiled as part of the container image build—it seems like it needs a working Magento installation (which I'm not guaranteed to have when *building* the container) to compile.

So currently what I'm doing is, when a new container starts up (e.g. when autoscaling, or when updating code, and new containers are replacing old ones):

- Check if Magento is installed.
- If it is installed, run:

  - `bin/magento module:enable --all`
  - `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

This seems to work okay, and the new container works just like the old/existing ones—if I don't do the compilation step, I just get lots of fatal exceptions until I do the compilation.

But my question is this: is there some other/better way of handling the `generated/` directory when you want to run Magento on multiple hosts/containers?

Should I share the `generated/` directory via NFS like I do for `var/`? It seems that reading code out of that directory would be a lot slower with NFS... and maybe the extra minute or so it takes to start a new container is worth the tradeoff to have each container compile/optimize it's own DI code (vs. sharing the directory with other existing containers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why this question got downvoted; looking around the Internet there is precious little information about how people should run Magento 2 (Open Source or Enterprise) in a scalable, production, container environment, and there are a *lot* of little things that are a pain in the butt to handle.

Relating to my question above, I am now compiling the code in the container build process, which *seems* to work okay; in the Dockerfile, after I've copied or cloned my Magento codebase into the container image:

```
# Compile code.
RUN magento module:enable --all \
 && magento setup:di:compile
```

That way I don't have to do that in an entrypoint script.

However, I do still have to run something like the following in my entrypoint—at least after a fresh installation (and maybe also after new deployments):

```
echo "Setting MAGE_MODE"
magento deploy:mode:set $ENV_MODE --skip-compilation

echo "Cleaning Magento Cache"
magento cache:flush
magento cache:clean

echo "Ensuring permissions are correct on Magento folders - post install."
CHOWN_PATHS_POST_INSTALL="app/etc generated pub/media pub/static var"
chown -R www-data:www-data $CHOWN_PATHS_POST_INSTALL

if [ "$ENV_MODE" = "production" ]; then
    echo "Compiling static assets."
    su -s /bin/bash -c "magento setup:static-content:deploy --jobs 4" www-data
fi
```

I'm still trying to figure out some other things, but I'm to the point where new containers can start in just a few seconds (still have to do things like `chown -R www-data:www-data` paths like `app/etc` and `generated` after the container starts, and copy/insert a templated `app/etc/env.php` file into place (to make sure all my site's settings are accounted for and can be driven by environment variables in the container so it's a true 12 factor app deployment).

Comment: this is actually a great question and I am curious to know the answer. Very little information about Magento and Kupernotes around, and it seems container deployment is the way to go for the future.

Answer (score 0):

are you using PVC for data persistence, I am trying to achieve this but am unable to can you please share the Dockerfile